# How to register a user that can be of a number of types in nestjs?

Tags: node.js, typescript, design-patterns, nestjs

The situation is plain and clear. I've got a user that can be a fighter, judge, location provider etc. All these users have some common props, like first name, second name, phone number, email etc. It's logical to have a dto called RegisterBasicUserDto that would have all those props. Now I want to have the fighter-related props on RegisterFighterDto, similarly for all the other types of user.

Then I would like to use the nestjs swagger and the class-validator library. The problem is that , to my surprise, typescript does not allow multiple inheritance and swagger decorators don't work with mixins meaning that I can't have RegisterUserDto that would extend all those types of users inheriting all the necessary props from those classes...

It forces me to dump all props into a single class, let's say RegisterUserDto and use it like that:

```
@Post('register')
public async registerUser(@Body() registerUserDto: RegisterUserDto): Promise<void> {}
```

I hate the idea that I will have to dump them all together to the point where I'm starting to think of making separate endpoints for each type of user. Even though that would lead to code duplication...

Maybe you've got better ideas. Would appreciate your help.

Comment: why not add a `role` property as an enum to represent the user's role? then you can use it in the DTO as an enum and do the optional validation using the class-validator ??

Comment: @HaniGhazi Oh yeah, I forgot to mention it, there's such a property, and it is an enum, but how does it save me from the necessity of lumping the properties belonging to all those types of users into that single dto?

Comment: @HaniGhazi I mean if I register a fighter I will need to receive his weight, his height, the number of wins etc, if I register a judge, I need his judge class etc, and all those props will be in a single dto...it will be just a medley of props...I'm trying to avoid it.

Comment: can you share your schemas? @Albert